# Is there a way to test an iPhone App on my iPod touch without registering with Apple?

Tags: iphone

Is there a manual way to load an iPhone App onto the iPod touch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not unless you jailbreak it. The code has to be signed in order for it to run on an actual iPhone or iPod touch.

Comment: Are there jailbroken iPod OSs available for this purpose?

Comment: I am not sure if you can take an application from XCode and then easily place it on a jailbroken phone.

Comment: OK, looks like I'm gonna need to go with the developer membership.

Comment: Actually, this is very easy to do!

Comment: See my post below, I was on my iPod itself for the last comment and I couldn't type that up on there :P.

Answer (score 20):

Yes, this does require a jailbreak. No, it won't brick your device, and it literally can't. Also, just click one button ("restore") in iTunes and it is gone, so it won't really void your warranty either. Also, if you do sign up afterwards, the Apple program works fine on JB'd devices (and you get access to *background apps* and other "horrible" features).

That being said, it is a reasonably trivial process to do. I'll outline a simple solution:

1. Edit 2: Check http://jailbrea.kr/ for the easiest way to jailbreak.
2. (No longer needed).
3. Open up Cydia, wait for it to sort things out, relaunch it. Once it is done downloading, search for "OpenSSH" and install it. Next three steps are optional but otherwise you might get a worm. Basically, you need to change the default password to something else. Its like leaving your computer with no password and connected online: very dumb.
4. Find your iPod's IP address. Its listed in the default Settings app on the device.
5. Open up Terminal on the Mac, then: `ssh -l root IP_OF_IPOD`, of course using the real IP of your iPod. Password is `alpine`.
6. Change your password, for security: `passwd`. Type in the old password (still `alpine`), then make up a new one and enter it twice. iPod secured.
7. K, time for Xcode. Open up this site: http://www.iphonedevwiki.net/index.php?title=Xcode
8. To get files of the device, a SFTP client like Cyberduck is useful.

Very easy process, just takes some time.

Comment: better than the chosen answer IMHO + 1

Comment: Yeah, I was a bit late here :P.

Comment: I may try it.  I need to get an iPod/phone first... If it works, I will transfer the check. +1 Thanks