# How can I deploy my iPhone app to my device without the Apple developer package?

Tags: iphone, xcode4

I recently purchased Xcode 4, and I would like to know how to deploy my apps to my device without jailbreaking it or paying Apple $99.

Comment: Why don't you sign up for the program then you can download Xcode for free for a year. Sounds like you chose the wrong option.

Comment: I bought it specifically to avoid doing that, but thanks anyways.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to test an iPhone App on my iPod touch without registering with Apple?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017609/is-there-a-way-to-test-an-iphone-app-on-my-ipod-touch-without-registering-with-ap)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must pay Apple $99 or jailbreak.

Comment: Jailbreaking in this case would be illegal as it would allow functionality you would otherwise have to pay for. (jailbreaking itself is not illegal though)

Answer (score 3):

You need to sign up with Apple as a developer (and pay the $99)

Comment: You won't get around it, period. Either you jailbreak it, or pay 99$. There is no other way.

Comment: I've found other ways for previous versions of Xcode. Specifically 2.x, but nothing for 4 so far. They involve self-signing certificates and whatnot.

Comment: I did it! Instructions are as follows:
1. Go to Keychain Access, select "Create a Certificate" from the Keychain menu.
2. Name: iPhone Developer
   Certificate Type: Code Signing
   Let Me Override Defaults: Yes
   Click continue.
3. Validity: 3650 days.
   Click continue.
4. Leave e-mail field empty, and click continue repeatedly until done.
   Keychain Access will tell you that the certificate is not trusted, this is fine.

Comment: (cont'd)
5. Open Terminal and enter the following:
   sudo /usr/bin/sed -i .bak 's/XCiPhoneOSCodeSignContext/XCCodeSignContext/'         /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Info.plist
6. In Xcode 4, beside the "Run" and "Stop" buttons, choose your device to run the app on. Done.

Answer (score -1):

@Ken Pespisa, STEP 5. (for xcode 4.3:)

```
sudo /usr/bin/sed -i .bak 's/XCiPhoneOSCodeSignContext/XCCodeSignContext/' /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Info.plist
```