# iOS developer program need to get provisioning profile

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, ios5

I'm using xcode 4.0. Do i need to join ios developer program at 99dollars to get a provisioning profile. My main purpose is to build an ipa file for free.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to test an iPhone App on my iPod touch without registering with Apple?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017609/is-there-a-way-to-test-an-iphone-app-on-my-ipod-touch-without-registering-with-a)

Comment: See also [Test app on iPhone without paying $99 to Apple](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024704/test-app-on-iphone-without-paying-99-to-apple)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run your application on the device you need to subscribe to an iOS Developer program. To create an application that runs on device you need to sign application with developer or adhoc certificate, so in order to create those certificates you need to sign up for Developer program.

http://developer.apple.com/programs/which-program/

http://developer.apple.com/programs/start/ios/

Answer (score 4):

Yes, Absolutely. Even if you give away your app for free you need to pay apple the $99/year fee.

Answer (score 2):

Provisioning profile is only avaliable when log in with developer account

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to pay to test/run on non-jailbroken devices and submit applications to the appstore. Welcome to the world of Apple. Some of the developer program will allow several developers in the same team to have provisioning profiles of their own however.

Comment: Note that you can only add other developers to your account if you sign up as a company. If you join as an individual, it's just you -- no team members.

Comment: Given they are the same price, is there any point in not getting the company one?

Comment: Well, to join as a company, you have to actually *have* a company and be able to provide relevant documentation when you sign up. It's easier to sign up as an individual.

Comment: Ah. Ok. That bit was always done for me :)